# Error 404 al acceder al controlador de ASP .NET MVC 5 con JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un controlador de la siguiente manera

```
[Route("/Historial/{inicio}/{final}")]
public ActionResult Historial(int inicio, int final)
{
    Return PartialView();
}
```

He intentado acceder a ese controlador por medio de [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) con lo siguiente:

```
$('#HistorialDiv').load('/Historial/1/10');
```

Pero en la consola del navegador me devuelve un error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:18571/Historial/1/10

**¿Como podría acceder al controlador por medio de esa URL que le estoy asignado al `.load()`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analizando un poco

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

puedo observar que la idea es darle un contexto al servicio que expones

No se bajo que controller lo estas ubicando pero quizas si usas

```
public class Cliente : Controller
{

    [Route("cliente/{inicio:int}/{final:int}/historial")]
    public ActionResult Historial(int inicio, int final)
    {
        Return PartialView();
    }

}
```

creo que le aportas algo mas de contexto cuando se define

Tambien veria si el "/" que defines delante de Historial no podria estar afectando

Comment: Entonces por fuerza debe tener la referencia del controlador y de la vista para hacerlo?, porque un ultimo intento que hice fue `[Route(/Home/Historial/{inicio:int}/{final:int})]` pero no obtuve resultado positivo

Comment: intenta quitando la primer "/"